# What is AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding java equivalent in php?

Tags: java, php, encryption, checksum, block-cipher

I'm trying to port below java snippet to php but somehow the output generated from php is of no near match to that of java. What am I doing wrong?

Java snippet:

```
public static String generateChecksum(String requestId, String validationString) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
byte[] digestSeed = mDigest.digest(requestId.getBytes());
byte[] seedEncArray = Arrays.copyOf(digestSeed, 32);
SecretKeySpec skspec = new SecretKeySpec(seedEncArray, "AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skspec, iv);

byte[] finalByteArray = cipher.doFinal(validationString.getBytes());
String finalValue = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(finalByteArray), "utf-8");
return finalValue;
}
```

Java checksum input/output (dummy data):

```
requestId:
1052

validationString:
AP_TPBabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890txnref777923212218553AP2GW_TPB2552122185536001052

finalValue:
mpCL2oS91/Mm1Xerz3rYBTEXtXFRPDodixkcJAooENvrgsc4xzrd2EeIHgmbf8rdgobmVYKFwxc0N5514FLyLyrJrxV99VztoRKBJE8LDRqXIkhU4FrobNA5FYuhVrrF
```

Equivalent PHP snippet:

```
$requestId = '1052';
$validationString = 'AP_TPBabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890txnref777923212218553AP2GW_TPB2552122185536001052';

$digestSeed = hash('sha512', $requestId, true);
$seedEncArray = substr($digestSeed, 0, 32);

$finalByteArray = openssl_encrypt(
    $validationString,
    'AES-128-CBC',
    $seedEncArray,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    '0000000000000000'
);
$finalValue = base64_encode($finalByteArray);

echo 'finalByteArray: ' . $finalByteArray;
echo '<br />';
echo 'finalValue: ' . $finalValue;
echo '<br />';
```

PHP checksum output:

```
finalByteArray: �V/��X�"�5���ܪ⳻����|��>��F��G�h�|�9�6��{��Y
finalValue: AvxWL4+VDliBBwgiijWlqMzcqhjis7uZPGM/h3AhB8o+0e28fOyf6z7TE4lGy9FHm2jdfAGrOcA2k7F7trlZBg==
```

Comment: what is package of Base64 you use? because when I try, the result is different

Comment: org.apache.commons.codec.binary

Comment: my java result is MmSJNHBGoIkZyOjq0....

Comment: Sorry please now check again. Have updated the validationString.

Comment: If don't have to use CBC, get rid of it. Prefer authenticated encryption like AES-GCM

Answer (score 0):

Finally after many tries I accomplished the target result. Sample code attached:

```
function encrypt($requestId, $validationString) {
    $digestSeed = hash('SHA512', $requestId, true);
    $seedEncArray = substr($digestSeed, 0, 32);

    $finalByteArray = openssl_encrypt(
        $validationString,
        'AES256',
        $seedEncArray,
        OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
        str_repeat(chr(0), 16)
    );

    return base64_encode($finalByteArray);
}
```